# Android: AlertDialog is in front of the gallery

Tags: android

Here's what I'm making now.

```
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setView(layout)
                    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.create), null)
                    .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), null)
                    .create();

            alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Button btnCreate = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

                    btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String categoryTitle = etCategoryTitle.getText().toString();

                        }
                    });

                    ImageButton ibAdd = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.ibAdd);
                    ibAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                            try {
                                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
                            } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            alertDialog.show();
```

By clicking the ImageButton instance called `ibAdd`, the screen should move on to the gallery to pick an image. Here I managed to reach the gallery, but the problem is that **the alert dialog is still in front of the gallery**, so I cannot choose an image without closing the dialog first.

Any solutions for this matter?

Comment: Could you provide screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I myself just found out why. That was due to this line of code.

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

I deleted this code, replaced `getApplicationContext()`, the parameter of the alertDialog with `MyActivity.this` and now it's working as I intended.